# Unable to create team project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am having below issue while creating team project.

TF30172 : you are trying to create team project either without required permission or with in older version of team explorer.

VS2010,SP1 & TFS 2012  installed.

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you install http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2662296 and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Team Explorer 2012 to be able to create Team Projects.

It is not supported to create Team Projects for TFS 2012 from Team Explorer 2010 regardless of the Service Pack version. If you restrict how Team Projects are created (recommended) then you could just have Team Explorer 2012 on the TFS server. You would need to make sure that you update both when updated are available.